# Why am I being charged for EC2 despite under the free tiers hours

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have three (RHEL, Ubuntu and Windows 10) t2.micro free tier running instances, I have got notified by the Amazon that I am being charged for month of December, when I saw the summary, all the instances are under free tier limit, neither of them exceed the limit of 750 hrs, but still I am getting charged, Why?

I have also attached the snapshot

[billing details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vdwq.png)

Comment: It looks like between the top two groups you used 750 hours (393+357 hours), so what you're being charged for are the hours above that. Perhaps it's 750 hours across all instances, not per instance.

Comment: It is per month for 12 months. So @notquiteamonad is surely correct.

Comment: The wording says "750 hours per month of Linux, RHEL, or SLES t2.micro or t3.micro instance dependent on region". This is based on _total_ usage, not "per instance".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've used the monthly 750 hours across the RHEL instances (393 hours) and the first 357 hours of the other Linux instances. So the additional 387 hours you've used on top of that on other Linux instances this month are outside the free tier, and are being billed for.

The exact wording on the [Free Tier page](https://aws.amazon.com/free) is:

> 750 hours per month of Linux, RHEL, or SLES t2.micro or t3.micro instance dependent on region
> 750 hours per month of Windows t2.micro or t3.micro instance dependent on region

I would interpret that to mean that you can have 750 hours of Linux, SLES, and RHEL instances (with 750 being the total, no matter how you split it), ***and*** 750 hours on Windows instances.

So I would assume that you can have 1500 hours per month *total* if you split evenly between Windows and Linux types. I should note though that this is my interpretation from the wording and is not guaranteed to be accurate.

To clarify for your comment, multiple instances having the same OS (including if one has RHEL, another has Other Linux as in your case) are considered a single unit in terms of billing.

Comment: Okay, so say for suppose if I have combination of two or more platform having same OS(linux+linux, win+win) , so as per your statement, the combination will be considered as single unit, isn't, please correct me?

Comment: Hi @MohammadZiaKhan, I've edited my answer to hopefully better cover your comment. But yes, if they're the same OS group the hours will be cumulative.

Answer (score 0):

You might have used it for more than 12 months, its free for 1 year use only or 750 hrs

Comment: 750 hours per month for 12 months, just to clarify.